# How to change font size in autocomplete dropbox

Tags: 11.04, gtkrc

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I probably need to change something in theme `gtkrc` file, but I can't find what needs to be changed so that I reduce font size by one unit

Just for reference, I found similar question on SO (although it's about Ubuntu 11.10): [How to change the highlight color in autocomplete box in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012176/how-to-change-the-highlight-color-in-autocomplete-box-in-eclipse), which shows that even Eclipse is using this from system setting, but to be more confusing font there is smaller (like I want it to be)

Comment: What app you are using?

Comment: it's global setting - on screenshot it's Geany

Comment: If you change Geany's font size by CTRL + mouse wheel, the size of the font size in the autocomplete dropbox also changes. Do you want to be able to change independently from the font size of the editor?

Comment: As said it's not about Geany, it's system setting and it's same in SciTE or other editors. I want autocomplete dropbox with smaller font then regular text, if possible. Like calltips, but it seems to me that calltips are customizable by editors while autocomplete is system set

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible with a gtkrc modification.

Even if you add this code to the end of your gtkrc:

```
style "fontchangetest" {
    font_name = "Sans 20"
}

class "GtkWidget" style "fontchangetest"
```

Restart Geany (or any GTK2 application for that matter) and a lot of the UI widgets will take this property, however the actual code editor and autocomplete list will retain the font designated by Geany.

However, let's check out the source code:

```
apt-get source geany
cd geany-0.20
```

The font for the autocomplete box is defined in scintilla/ScintillaBase.cxx, line 264:

```
ac.lb->SetFont(vs.styles[STYLE_DEFAULT].font);
```

The `SetFont` function is only used for the autocomplete listbox (verified with '[ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) SetFont'), so no harm in changing it.

Open up scintilla/PlatGTK.cxx, navigate to line 2029. You'll see this code:

```
void ListBoxX::SetFont(Font &scint_font) {
    // Only do for Pango font as there have been crashes for GDK fonts
    if (Created() && PFont(scint_font)->pfd) {
        // Current font is Pango font
        gtk_widget_modify_font(PWidget(list), PFont(scint_font)->pfd);
    }
}
```

Replace it with:

```
void ListBoxX::SetFont(Font &scint_font) {
    // Only do for Pango font as there have been crashes for GDK fonts
    if (Created() && PFont(scint_font)->pfd) {
        // Current font is Pango font
        PangoFontDescription* pf = pango_font_description_from_string("Sans 6");
        gtk_widget_modify_font(PWidget(list), pf);
    }
}
```

Obviously you can change the 'Sans 6' to be whatever font and size you like. This is a very hacky solution, however I don't know C/C++ so perhaps there's a more elegant way to do it.

Then you can either:

```
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

To do a quick compile and install (would seriously advise removing the existing geany package first though)

Or the more correct way:

```
sudo aptitude install build-essential devscripts ubuntu-dev-tools \
debhelper dh-make diff patch cdbs quilt gnupg fakeroot lintian \
pbuilder piuparts intltool chrpath

debuild
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i geany_0.20-1.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

To build a new package including the changes and then install it.

Comment: WOW... great answer, thanks. So all my editors show same autocomplete box because they all use same Scintilla component. Rebuilding SciTE for example is fine solution, I wanted to add other custom patch anyway